# Let $M$ be a non-trivial $R$-module having no non-trivial submodule; then every non-trivial $R$-homomorphism on $M$ is isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an irreducible $R$-module such that $\exists r_0 \in R$, $\exists m_0 \in M$ such that $r_0m_0 \ne 0$. Then how to prove that any $R$-homomorphism $T$ of $M$ into $M$ is either an isomorphism or is trivial ( i.e. $T(m)=0, \forall m \in M$ )

Comment: What have you done so far? What do you know in general about module homomorphisms and submodules that might allow you to use the irreducibility?

Comment: @JohnBrevik :Not much , I only know that simple i.e. irreducible unital $R$-modules are cyclic and very basic properties of module homomorphisms

Comment: What basic properties? By definition your module has no nontrivial submodules; anything regarding homomorphisms and submodules?

Comment: @JohnBrevik: yes , $ker T , Im T$ are submodules ; so $\ker T$ is either trivial or the whole module , so either $T$ is trivial or $T$ is injective ; but can we show $T$ is surjective ? and I think I'm not using that $M$ is non-trivial ...

Comment: Good work with ker. What about Im? (I don't think that non-trivial is really necessary here.)

Comment: @JohnBrevik : yes right ; if $Im T$ is trivial , then so is $T$ , and otherwise $Im T$ is whole $M$ so surjective , am I correct ?

Comment: That's what I had in mind :)

Comment: @JohnBrevik : :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $T\colon M\to M$ be an $R$-homomorphism such that $T(x)\ne0$ for some $x\in M$.

Then $x\notin\ker T$, which forces $\ker T=\{0\}$, because the $R$-submodules of $M$ are $\{0\}$ and $M$.

Similarly the image of $T$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$ and it is not $\{0\}$, so…